# Inserting language characters in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, mod-python

I am following the link http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual-model/ Basically i am trying to insert hindi characters into mysql db

I have created the files in the test directory as in the above said link and using django version 1.1 an dpython version is 2.4.3

I geta error message as the following.

```
  from testlanguages import Language,BookTranslation,Book
  >>> lang_pl = Language(code="pl", name="Polish")
  >>> lang_pl.save()
  >>> book_pl.language = lang_pl
  >>> book_pl.save()
  >>> lang_hi = Language(code="hi", name="Hindi")
  >>> lang_hi.save()
  >>> book_hi = BookTranslation()
  >>> book_hi.title = "का सफल प्रक्षेपण किया है. इस राकेट ने पाँच"  Sum characters as in bbc.co.uk/hindi
  >>> book_hi.description = "का सफल प्रक्षेपण किया है. इस राकेट ने पाँच" Sum characters as in bbc.co.uk/hindi
  >>> book_hi.model = book
  >>> book_hi.language = lang_hi
  >>> book_hi.save()
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in ?
    File "/opt/project/django/django/db/models/base.py", line 410, in save
    self.save_base(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
    File "/opt/project/django/django/db/models/base.py", line 495, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk)
    File "/opt/project/django/django/db/models/manager.py", line 177, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/project/django/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in insert_query
    return query.execute_sql(return_id)
    File "/opt/project/django/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 320, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(InsertQuery, self).execute_sql(None)
    File "/opt/project/django/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2369, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params) 
    File "/opt/project/django/django/db/backends/util.py", line 19, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/opt/project/django/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 84, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 165, in execute
    self._warning_check()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 80, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/warnings.py", line 61, in warn
    warn_explicit(message, category, filename, lineno, module, registry)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/warnings.py", line 96, in warn_explicit
        raise message
        Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\x95\xE0\xA4\xBE...' for column 'title' at row 1
```

How to resolve this.

Is there any easy method to insert the special characters into DB

Comment: And the python version i am using is 2.4.3

Comment: Python 3 makes it easier to avoid errors like these.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is most likely a MySQL problem, which doesn't always support Unicode characters by default.

You should probably declare the `DEFAULT CHARSET` to `utf8` and `DEFAULT COLLATION` to `utf8_general_ci` on your database (use the `ALTER DATABASE` or modify the `CREATE DATABASE` statements, as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-database.html)).

Comment: I tried this,and still get the same error
alter database project COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
alter database project CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: If you can, recreate the database as utf8, as I'm not sure if the alter database also modifies tables and columns inside the database.  


You should probably try Ignacio's suggestion, too.

Comment: Don't use MySQL's `utf8` encoding, instead, use `utf8mb4`. This is because MySQL only uses three bytes per character when using `utf8`, and you will need to have four, so you need to set `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using bytestrings. Start using `unicode`.

```
book_hi.title = u"का सफल प्रक्षेपण किया है. इस राकेट ने पाँच"
```

Comment: i had got an error as described so was trying something else..So had left a question in the other post..

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(  host = "localhost",
            user = "root",
            passwd = "",
            db = "test");

conn.set_character_set('utf8')
```

this code will solve you problem

**Note *.**  `conn.set_character_set('utf8')` **is notable part**